# Integral extension of a DVR which is of finite type over a field $k$

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ be a DVR over an algebraically closed field $k$ and $K=\operatorname{Frac}R$.
Assume that a field $k^{\prime}$ of finite type over $k$ and a finite field extension $K\subset K^{\prime}=K\otimes k^{\prime}$ are given.

Then I want to prove the following,

> There is an integral extension $R\subset R^{\prime}$ s.t. $R^{\prime}$ is a DVR of $K^{\prime}$.

My attempt:
Take the integral closure $\widetilde{R}$ of $R$ in $K^{\prime}$, this is a Dedekind domain. Localize $\widetilde{R}$ at some maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}^{\prime}$, then $\widetilde{R}_{\mathfrak{m}^{\prime}}$ is a DVR of $K^{\prime}$.

But, I don't think $R\subset \widetilde{R}_{\mathfrak{m}^{\prime}}$ is an integral extension in general, and I'm stuck.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, $R$ can't be of finite type over $k$. I must have some misunderstanding, so I'll fix my question.

Comment: The case of $R$ being the localization at a prime ideal of a finitely generated $k$-algebra may be more interesting.